# Changing the blue status bar in ios6

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

At times, the status bar changes color to blue. Need it to be black throughout the whole app. I would like to change the blue status bar back to black. How do i change it back. Need some help on this. Thanks.

The image looks like this:

[image]

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];

Comment: Or go to your target's settings and on the summary tab you can change the tint of your status bar.

Comment: add your comments as answers, I wil upvote for you...

Answer (score 3):

You can change it from, Target Settings -> Summery -> tint of status bar

Or

you can change it back to black from, info.plist -> set value for status bar style as opaque black style.

Answer (score 2):

add the following code for the status bar:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
```

Answer (score 1):

The status bar color its managed by the current tint color of the navigation bar, if you want to set a different color just set the tint color in Interface Builder and it will change it for you automatically when the controller its visible, [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque]; will force the legacy colors to change the status bar appearance, but you cant change to a different color without the correspondent tint color for the navigation bar.